# Electrons in the nuclei

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, elementary-particles

Is it possible that electrons would switch place with the protons in the atom? So that the electrons in the nuclei and the protons hover around them.
Is it even possible? And why?

Answer (score 1):

No. Electrons will repel each other. Protons are able to form a nucleus together with neutrons due to strong interaction which overcomes the Coulomb repulsion between protons at nuclear distances. Electrons do not participate in the strong interaction.

Comment: Why can't they?

Comment: The heavier subatomic is in the nucleus. But a negativ charged particle can be there also. In antimatter the anti-proton together with neutrons form the nucleus and positrons are in shells around.

Comment: Yes, but the anti-proton is an anti-hadron which means that it interacts strongly. It's not that the electrons cannot be in the nucleus because their electric charge is negative, but rather because they do not participate in the strong interaction, so they cannot bind together to form a nucleus.